# Salesforce1 Lightning Page Standard Global Quick Actions

Tags: salesforce1-app, chatter, lightning-apps, global-actions, app-builder

I created a custom Lightning Page for Salesforce1 using the Lightning App Builder. I want to add the standard quick actions in the Action Bar menu like Chatter Post or Chatter Pole actions. But I can only see Custom Quick Actions when I try to add them to my page. Is there a way to enable and add Standard Quick Actions like Chatter Post or Chatter Pole to a custom Salesforce1 Lightning page?

[image]

[image]

The available action list does not show the Chatter Post or Chatter Pole quick actions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that feed tracking is not available for Lightning pages, so you can only create new global action and add it to your page actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Salesforce Help, [How Actions Work with Lightning Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lightning_page_actions.htm):

> App Home pages support only global actions.
>
> Standard Chatter actions, such as Post, File, Link, and Poll, aren’t
>   supported.

This is most likely because there's no Chatter feed on app home pages -- all the standard Chatter actions on the record home pages in Lightning pages get pulled into the Collaborate tab.